# How to store a file location into an entry widget - Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, grid

I'm having  a trouble to store a file location into a entry widget for my script using Tkinter:

So far I was able to have a browse button working perfectly, however, I cannot assing the variable value that I created `parent.filename` to store the file location into a entry widget like the photo below shows:

[image]

My script following below:

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import os
import Tkinter, Tkconstants, tkFileDialog

class arquivos:

    def __init__(self, parent):     

       parent.title('TEXT MINING - HMB QA')

       self.gif1 = PhotoImage(file = 'tteste.gif')
       label1 = Label(image=self.gif1)
       label1.image = self.gif1 
       label1.grid(row = 0, column = 0, rowspan=13, sticky=NW)

       Label(parent, text='File URL:').grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='e')
       self.v1=Entry(parent, width=90)
       self.v1.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='we',columnspan=8)


       self.button3 = Button(parent, text = "Browse", command 
       =self.loadtemplate, width = 10, height=1)        
       self.button3.grid(row=0, column=10, columnspan=2, sticky='w')

       Label(parent, text='Filter RO List:').grid(row=1, column=1, 
       sticky='e')
       self.v2=Radiobutton(parent, text="YES", value=1)
       self.v2.grid(row=1,column=2, columnspan=1, sticky='w')

parent=Tk()
arquivos(parent)
parent.mainloop(
```

Regarding the function `loadtemplate` follows the code:

```
 def loadtemplate(self): 

    parent.filename = StringVar()        
    parent.filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",title 
    = "Select file",filetypes = (("jpeg files","*.jpg"),("all 
    files","*.*")))
    print parent.filename        
    self.v20 = Entry(parent, textvariable=parent.filename, width=90)
    self.v20.grid(row=0,column=2, sticky='we',columnspan=8)
```

When I hit the `Browse` button a box pops out and I can select the file directory: 
The variable `parent.filename` assigned to store the file location also  works, however, I'm not able to store the variable value into the entry widget `self.v1`

Any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is you're overwriting `StringVar` instance on `parent.filename` with a destination string. Use `set` method to set the value of the variable class 
object in `parent.filename` instead.

Replace:

```
parent.filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",title 
    = "Select file",filetypes = (("jpeg files","*.jpg"),("all 
    files","*.*")))
```

with:

```
parent.filename.set(tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",title 
    = "Select file",filetypes = (("jpeg files","*.jpg"),("all 
    files","*.*"))))
```